# I know R is closed and open but is it a closed and open interval?

Tags: real-analysis

I know $\mathbb{R}$ is open and closed but is this the same as saying it's an open interval and a closed interval?

Comment: What is your definition of "interval"?

Comment: We've never really defined interval, but I guess since I know $\mathbb{R}=(-\infty,\infty)$, then it's an open interval. Not sure about closed interval.

Comment: In my experience it's often considered an open interval.  It's not usually considered a closed interval because a closed interval ought to include its extrema.  But it's pretty much a convention.  Just don't let whatever definition you use make sure you don't make  unwarranted assumption. It's useful to assume it's an open interval when you have the theory that all open sets in R are a union of disjoint intervals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *really* depends on your working definition of "interval" — that is, your textbook's definition or your teacher's.

If "interval" is defined as:

> 1. $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an interval $\iff$ there are $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $I$ is one of $[a,b], [a,b), (a,b]$ or $(a,b)$

then **No**, $\mathbb{R}$ is not an interval.

However, if "interval" is defined as:

> 2. $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an interval $\iff$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a \le b$, if $a, b \in I$ then $[a, b] \subseteq I$

then **Yes**, $\mathbb{R}$ *is* an interval.

*NOTES*

- According to 2., not just $\mathbb{R}$ itself but also all half-unbounded "rays" like $(-\infty, a)$ and $[b, +\infty)$ are intervals. According to 1., however, they are not.
- Definition 1. is more restrictive. BUT, if 1. is relaxed to allow $a, b \in \overline {\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, +\infty\}$, then the resulting definition is equivalent to 2.

In any case, $\mathbb{R}$ is *not* a **closed** interval, because if any "closed interval" contains its inf and sup; however, the "extended real $-\infty = \inf(\mathbb{R}) \notin \mathbb{R}$ (and similarly for $\sup$ and $+\infty$).

Comment: What if we defined $(a,b)=\{x:a<x<b\}$ and $[a,b]=\{x:a\leq x\leq b\}$? Is this equivalent to 2?

Comment: Saying that an interval is closed is again a question of definitions; $\mathbb{R}$ ***is*** a closed set.

Comment: @egreg exactly, and $\inf(X)$ [$\sup(X)$] $\in \overline X$ for $X$ bounded below [above]. OP: re those definitions in your comment/question: those would be equivalent to 1. (I'll give the two statements numbers now : ), assuming $a, b$ are actual/finite real numbers and can't be $±\infty$. That's a 3rd possibility I anticipated but didn't write up. If $a, b$ can be *extended* reals, then the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: How would one write $\mathbb{R}$ as a closed interval though?

Comment: @Moz One cannot: see the paragraph of my answer that begins "In any case, ℝR is not a closed interval". Because it would contain its endpoints, and then, what could those be? (not real numbers) The set does not contain a greatest element, so it's not closed on the right in the ']' sense; and it doesn't contain a least element, so it's not closed on the left in the '[' sense.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was looking for a function that has domain of a closed interval but range of an open interval but now it seems impossible.

Comment: @Moz You mean a *continuous* function, whose entire range is an open interval? Then you'll be searching forever: there aren't any :) $[a,b]$ is *compact*, and the continuous image of a compact set/space is compact as well. In $\mathbb{R}$, "compact" means "closed and bounded" (by the [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem ).

Comment: But what if I consider the closed interval $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: @Moz Well, the main problem is that $[0, +\infty)$ is a closed set but not necessarily a "closed interval" (again, the latter is just a matter of terminology, very sensitive to definition of "interval").

Comment: @BrianO: (1/2) many people, especially those that are used to topology would disagree with your last sentence. That's again a matter of definition: 1) If you define a closed interval $I$ as "an interval of $\mathbb R$ that contains its endpoint" (I guess you mean $inf(I)$ and $sup(I)$ by endpoints), then $\mathbb R$ is a closed interval of $\mathbb R$,  as the definition is vacuously satisfied, since $\mathbb R$ has no endpoints. 2) You mention $\overline{\mathbb R}$, so you may want to define a closed interval $I$ as "an interval of $\overline{\mathbb R}$ that contains its endpoint"

Comment: (2/2) and then $\mathbb R$ is not a closed interval of $\overline{\mathbb R}$. I am not sure that the OP was considering $\overline{\mathbb R}$. Note that the notion of closed is usually a topological notion and may depend on the context. 
3) A definition that I find confusing: the ubiquitous Stewart's Calculus textbook defines a closed interval as an interval of the form $[a,b]$ ($a,b$ real numbers). All the others, in particular $\mathbb R$, are not closed.

Comment: @Taladris I agree, no end of potential debate over this, but my only point is, OP's original question skirts the boundary of possible definitions of "closed interval" — and there are at least two. In any case it's sort of a trivial point and we shouldn't flame about it, we just have to recognize the distinctions that need to be observed.

Comment: @BryanO: then I feel that the "in any case" of your last sentence is misleading: there are definitely cases (and important ones!) where $\mathbb R$ is considered as closed. (Or is your last sentence supposed to be part of your second note, where you introduce the extended real line).

Comment: @Taladris No intention to mislead or befuddle, & I don't believe I've done so. $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$, an open set and an open interval in the extended reals $\mathbb{\overline R}$.

Comment: You can also define "interval" to mean "a connected subset of $\Bbb R$." On a related note, $\varnothing$ should be considered an interval, I think; the definition $(a,b)=\{x\mid a<x<b\}$ implies that $\varnothing=(1,0)=(0,0)$. (People don't agree on whether $\varnothing$ should be considered connected, though. Apparently it's like how $1$ isn't considered prime. I think it should be connected.)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Yep that's what my 2nd definition covers, which is the one I favor. In fact i hesitated about stipulating any order between $a$ and $b$ in the first definition. $\emptyset$ is, by the 2nd definition, a perfectly good interval, as are singletons. *imho* the definition of "interval" should be the same as when you're dealing with an arbitrary order topology.

Comment: Argh, looking at where I wrote $(1,0)$ above, my brain is having a hard time reading that like an interval (since it makes so much more sense as an ordered pair). Maybe I should use ${]1,0[}\subset\Bbb R$ and $\langle1,0\rangle\in\Bbb R^2$ to disambiguate? (…I think I'll just stick with the ambiguous parentheses, actually.)